# Hacked site created foreign language tags pages, can we block them in robots.txt to remove them from Google?

Tags: wordpress, robots.txt, title, hacked-site

Our WordPress website was hacked which is now revamped and updated to the WP v5.0.3  but still `Tags` and `35fc4a-50164960-421910 or 6d285b-31601402-365308` type URLs are indexed in Google.

Can we block `Tags-205297-` type URLs with robots.txt to URLs starting with `Tags` sign?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do those pages still work if you click on them?   If so you still have more hacking cleanup work to do.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller pages are not working if we click on them

Comment: Then Emirodgar's suggestion of using the URL removal tool is probably your best bet.   Robots.txt blocks crawling but not indexing.   So if you disallow them there, Google won't be able to crawl them to see that they are gone.  Using robots.txt will make it take longer to get them removed from Google.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller can we remove individual links from the Google URLs Removal Tool?

Comment: Yes, it will be a pain if there are a lot of them though.  Your other option is just to wait.  They will get removed on their own, but it may take months.

Answer (score 2):

If your Wordpress has been hacked, the first thing is remove the infection. [Follow these instructions](https://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked).

After that, you could prevent the indexing using [noindex tag](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_meta_tag?hl=en). You can speed up the deindexation throwing an `error 404` or `error 410` or with a `301 redirect`. Using the robots.txt disallow command will take to long and maybe won't work,

You can also use the [URL removal tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/url-removal) but you must delete one URL by the time and it's just temporal so, after that, make sure you use the noindex tag.

Comment: i have done all these steps and can we block `tags` url by robots.txt or .htaccess?

Comment: Yes, you can block with robots.txt and through .htaccess you can apply a 301 redirect

Comment: how do i block these type of URLs `35fc4a-50164960-421910` `6d285b-31601402-365308` there are so many URLs indexed on the google with the different numbers?

Comment: @Emirodgar I would caution against suggesting the use of robots.txt to block these pages, because if you block the pages then Googlebot will never see that they are 404/410/301, and they could stay in the search index for a long time.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Indeed, he has to use one of the two options, but not both at the same time. My previous comment was not clear enough.